# Class redesign - Passing an object to ITestResult without using Reporter.getCurrentTestResult()

Tags: java, testng

Requesting your kind time and solution to a possible flaw in my class design. 
Below is an explanation plus a working example.
Thank You for your valuable time and attention.

**About:**

- I am using TestNG 6.11 to setup test scripts.
- Each Test Class `Run1, Run2 etc...` is derived from a Base Test `BaseRun`.
- Each Test Class contains multiple @Test methods.
- Each @Test method must first acquire a `unique test session` before running the test steps.
- This `unique test session` is nothing a new instance of `ExtentTest` for the
  current `ExtentReport`
- Once the tests complete the tests results are saved into the extent report.
- Importantly, the tests must run accurately when running parallel suites/tests from the NG xml.

**The Problem is in my current class design:**

- The base class `BaseRun` does not know the Unique Test Session it has spawned.
- Refer `getSession()` in `BaseRun`

**The Solution that i currently use is:**

- In the `@Test`, i am manually injecting the TestSession into the ITestResult.
- I must do this so that in `@AfterMethod` i am able to correctly perform reporting for the correct test session.

  > These are the lines under `Run1.java` that do this injection...
  >       ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
  >       result.setAttribute("session", testSession);

**Question is:**

- How can i avoid injecting the TestSession from inside @Test?
- Is there a more dynamic way, maybe something that is abstracted?
- What changes i need to do to my current class design?

**Run1.java**

```
public class Run1 extends BaseRun {

    @Test
    void runner1(){
        ExtentTest testSession = getSession("Testing Runner 1");
        ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        result.setAttribute("session", testSession);
        testSession.log(Status.INFO, "performing Runner1 Step1");
        testSession.log(Status.INFO, "performing Runner1 Step2");
    }

    @Test
    void runner2(){
        ExtentTest testSession = getSession("Testing Runner 2");
        ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        result.setAttribute("session", testSession);
        testSession.log(Status.INFO, "performing Runner2 Step1");
        testSession.log(Status.INFO, "performing Runner2 Step2");       
        assertTrue(false);
    }           
}
```

**BaseRun.java**

```
public class BaseRun {

    Reports MyExtentReport; 

    @BeforeSuite void setup(){ MyExtentReport = new Reports(); }

    @AfterSuite void teardown(){ MyExtentReport.save();}

    public ExtentTest getSession(String testName){
        return MyExtentReport.createTest(testName);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    void doSomeReporting(ITestResult result){       
        ExtentTest extentTest = (ExtentTest) result.getAttribute("session");
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS){
            extentTest.pass(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed.", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
            extentTest.skip(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " skipped.", ExtentColor.YELLOW));
            extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable());
        }
        else{
            extentTest.fail(MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed.", ExtentColor.RED));
            extentTest.fail(result.getThrowable());
        }
    }   
}
```

**Reports.java**

```
public class Reports {

    public ExtentReports extentReports;

    public Reports(){
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\test-output\\extent.html");
        ExtentHtmlReporter reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(file);
        reporter.setAppendExisting(false);
        extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        extentReports.attachReporter(reporter);
    }

    public ExtentTest createTest(String testName){
        return extentReports.createTest(testName);
    }

    public void save(){
        extentReports.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following :

1. Create an annotation using which you can indicate the unique session identifier that you would like a test method to be associated with.
2. You now enhance your base class to include a `@BeforeMethod` annotated method wherein you introspect the method to be executed, to check for the annotation [created in (1)] and if present, extract the session identifer from it and inject it as an attribute into your to be executed `@Test` method's `ITestResult` object.
3. Now within your `@AfterMethod` you should be able to easily extract out the attribute.

Using this approach you dont have to pollute your `@Test` annotated test method with all the logic of extracting the session id and explicitly injecting it into the `@Test` method's `ITestResult` object.

Here's a sample that shows all of this in action.

Your annotation can look like below

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface SessionId {
    String id();
}
```

Your modified base class can look like below

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class BaseRun {
    private String getSession(Method method) {
        SessionId id = method.getAnnotation(SessionId.class);
        if (id == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return id.id();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method, ITestResult result) {
        String id = getSession(method);
        result.setAttribute("session", id);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("Session Id = " + result.getAttribute("session"));
    }

}
```

And now your modified test class can look something like below

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Run1 extends BaseRun {
    @Test
    @SessionId(id = "Testing Runner 1")
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is a test case");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Note:**
I have intentionally skipped referring to the `ExtentReports` classes, because for including that I would need to be adding up the extent report related jars to my classpath.